# how to hide/and show previously opened div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to develop customized tooltip using html and Jquery.I am clicking on the Question icon and showing some text in tooltip.I am having two question icons with same class.My problem is when i click on first question icon,if second tooltip is visible then i want to hide second tooltip.I dont want both tooltip visible at a time.Below is the my code :

```
<div class="tab-container">
 <div class="policy-info-header">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">     
     <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs policy-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#policy-abstract" data-toggle="tab">Policy Abstract</a></li>
      <li><a href="#coverage-summary" data-toggle="tab">Coverage Summary</a></li>
     </ul>  
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>                      
<div class="container" role="main">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="policy-abstract">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <hr/>
       <div class="sub-wrapper">
         <span class="sub-title pull-left">Details</span>
         <ul class="policy-container">
         <li><span>Policy Number<i  id="policy-number" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign">
        <div class="description-box">This is a policy number from which user can understand policyThis is a policy number from which user can understand policy..</div>                         
</i>
</span>
<label>13656524</label>
</li>
<li>
<span>Status Change Date</span><label>06/15/2016</label>
</li>
<li>
<span>Group Number
<i  id="group-number" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign">
<div class="description-box">This is a policy number from which user can understand policyThis is a policy number from which user can understand policy..</div>                         
</i>
</span>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> 

JS:
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.policy-container span').on('click','i', function(e){ 
    //$(this).prev().find(".description-box").hide();
    //alert("p");
    $(this).find(".description-box").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
    $(".description-box").hide();  
    });
});
```

My working fiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/gbhopale/myrt7gpf/

Answer (score 2):

You can just hide all boxes when you click on the question mark and then open only proper one.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.policy-container span').on('click', 'i', function(e) {
     $(".description-box").hide();
     $(this).find(".description-box").show();
     e.stopPropagation();
   });
   $(document).click(function() {
     $(".description-box").hide();
   });
 });
```

### **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/myrt7gpf/5/)**

Comment: ok..got it..i was not hiding all boxes before showing it..thanks ..lots